# why when I press a Ctrl+Tab in a MultiLine TextBox,it enters a tab character, even i set the AcceptsTab property to false

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, textbox

Why does pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in a *MultiLine* `TextBox` enter a `tab` character even though I set the `AcceptsTab` property to `false`?

I set the `MultiLine` property to `true` and the `AcceptsTab` property to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ctrl-tab key press is treated differently from a tab key press. If you handle the Ctrl-tab in your `TextBox_KeyDown` event, you can ignore it:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```